# Javascript Access a Body Object as a Script using SCSS Classes originally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, fonts

As a non Programmer I try to use a Script form my Purpose and have to modify it, hope thats generally ok to you:

HTML in original Script:

```
<div class="tc-page-wrap">
</div>
```

SCSS / Less section:

```
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css);

.tc-page-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.random-tc-page-wrap:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f005";
}

$circle-size: 100px;
$colors: #FFD700, #FFF8DC, #DB7093, #C2B7FE, #95A9FF;
$shapes: '\f005', '\f0c8', '\f1db', '\f096', '\f1d8', '\f1cb';
$shape-count: 50;

@for $i from 1 through $shape-count {
    $shape-size: random(10);
    $rotation: random(360);
    $speed: 40 + random(10);
    $color-key: random( length($colors) );
    $shape-color: nth( $colors, $color-key );
    $shape-key: random( length($shapes) );
    $shape-type: nth( $shapes, $shape-key );
    $text: random(10);

    @keyframes tc-page-wrap-#{$i} {
        0% {
            transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotate(#{$rotation + 0}deg);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotate(#{$rotation + 360}deg);
        }
    }

    .tc-page-wrap-container--#{$i} { 
        animation: tc-page-wrap-#{$i} #{$speed}s linear infinite;

        .random-tc-page-wrap:after {
            margin: #{$shape-size}rem;
            color: $shape-color;
            font-size: #{$shape-size * 0.2}rem;
            content: $shape-type;
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript Part:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

var html = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i ++) {
    html += '<div class="tc-page-wrap-container--'+i+' tc-page-wrap- 
animation"><div class="random-tc-page-wrap"></div></div>';
}

document.querySelector('.tc-page-wrap').innerHTML += html;

});
```

I would like to put generated content into `<body>` Elemet, who could give some Help?

@dustytrash helped me to know where to look at. To implement a solution to the Website I’m trying to apply the content of the var html to a Style attribute. This seems not to work: ´document.getElementById('tc-page-wrap').style.background = html;´

Comment: It's a nice work from here I'm trying to use: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJaeeQ

Comment: Is your `<div class="tc-page-wrap">` outside the `<body>` element? Or is the problem that no content is being generated?

Comment: If you're just trying to move the generated content, change `document.querySelector('.tc-page-wrap').innerHTML += html;` to `document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += html;`

Comment: correction because editing was closed: I found your tip very usefull and it's a working answer so far, thanks.  also #tc-page-wrap works, as tc-page-wrap acually is a Div ID inside the Body. To easily integrate the solution to the existing Themplate, I should be able to us something like `document.querySelector('#tc-page-wrap{background-image: Url("TheRandomContent")}').innerHTML += html;` but. I'm using `#tc-page-wrap {
background: 
url(https://path/folder/bgtexture.jpg);}` to show a Background Image.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string concatenation. If you use jQuery, create your div using `var div = $('<div .....>...</div>');` and then add it into wherever you need it with `$('some query selector').append(div);`. Even if you use plain JS, don't use string concatenation, use the DOM API.

In this case, using jQuery:

```
// equivalent to $(document).ready(function() { ... })
$(function() {
  var container = $('.tc-page-wrap');
  for (var i = 1, inner, outer; i <= 50; i ++) {
    inner = $('<div class="random-tc-page-wrap"></div>');
    outer = $('<div class="tc-page-wrap-container--'+i+'tc-page-wrap-animation"></div>');
    outer.append(inner);
    container.append(outer);
  }
});
```

Also, if you use jQuery, use jQuery. Don't mix in plain JS unless it's for something jQuery can't do: if you or anyone else has to read the code at any point later in time, being consistent makes for easy to understand code.

Comment: Thanks for your input, in " var container = $('.tc-page-wrap');" I have to add " ' " for closing

Comment: I tried in codepen: https://codepen.io/scribbi/pen/RYmoGq, but the animation is not doing. in the Page I use ID instead of Class like:   `jQurey(function() {
  var container = $('#tc-page-wrap);
  for (var i = 1, inner, outer; i <= 50; i ++) {
    inner = $('<div class="random-tc-page-wrap"></div>');
    outer = $('<div class="tc-page-wrap-container--'+i+'tc-page-wrap-animation"></div>');
    outer.append(inner);
    container.append(outer);
  }
});` I can't get it work like that.

Comment: What do you mean? The previews shows 50 elements (with the fontawesome star as ::after content) in the body after running.

Comment: Using string concatenation the codepen test is working:  https://codepen.io/scribbi/pen/pOXjrd. The 50 stars showing are placeholder  right, and the result of the SCSS Instruction: `.random-tc-page-wrap:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f005";
}`